# writing functions and wrapping commands for abstraction

Tags: macros, programming, package-writing, write, alias

Can i write a little function (or macro or whatever) that wraps two commands (functions?) into one; united under a single alias?

Specifically I want to wrap `\input{}` and `\includegraphics{}` into a single little entity. So instead of having to:

```
\input                      {diagrams/TEX/fig1.tex}
\includegraphics[scale=0.27]{diagrams/PDF/fig2.pdf}
```

I'll be able to just do something like:

```
\in            {diagrams/TEX/fig1.tex}
\in[scale=0.27]{diagrams/PDF/fig2.pdf}
```

It's annoying that we need two remember two different commands to do what is essentially (at a high level/from a user perspective) the same thing, just because of the different file types.

Why? It's just a minor inconvenience, and I understand why it is the way it is, but little things like this are always causing me grief, and I'm all about streamlining my workflow. So I want to build a custom `preamble.sty` file with this kind of thing in it so I never have to waste time or energy fussing and fatiguing over pedantic little things like the difference between *input* and *include* or accidentally typing `\include` or `\inputgraphics`, and so on. I like it nice and easy to free my mind to focus on the more important things, like writing content.

Added from comment to question:

Tex is a programming language after all, and abstraction is a basic programming principle. The whole point of LaTeX is supposed to be the ability to focus on content. I'm in pursuit of progress.

Comment: Do you know about the `ginlctex` package?

Comment: @egreg I'm not familiar, but I'll look into it.

Comment: The distinction between `\input` and `\include` is not at all pedantic. However, if you risk to confuse between `\includegraphics` and `\inputgraphics`, you will probably also forget the abstract name you give. It's just a question of practice. A graphics object is not `\input`, because this name is reserved to text files; the similar command `\include` is mostly a relic of the past, when saving compilation time with big project was essential. Modern machines made it not as useful as it used to be.

Answer (score 1):

From the introduction in the manual of the `gincltex` package:

> This small package builds on the standard LaTeX package `graphicx` and allows external LaTeX source files to be included like graphic files:
>
> ```latex
> \includegraphics[〈options〉]{〈file〉.tex}
> ```
>
> A LaTeX file included this way should result in an identical display as a tightly cropped EPS or PDF image of the same file (apart smaller rounding differences). Usually such files hold a picture environment like `picture`, `pspicture`, `pgfpicture` or `tikzpicture`, which may take advantage from the `standalone` class. In fact `gincltex` is used in newer versions of `standalone` to seamlessly switch between source and image files.
>
> All options of `\includegraphics` described in the manual of `graphicx` (the `grfguide`) should be supported. Therefore it is possible to resize, rotate and clip the content of the LaTeX source file in the same way as for images.

Thus you just need to do

```latex
\usepackage{gincltex}
```

in your preamble and you can use

```latex
\includegraphics{diagrams/TEX/fig1.tex}
\includegraphics[scale=0.27]{diagrams/PDF/fig2.pdf}
```

You can also define an alias for `\includegraphics`, for instance

```latex
\newcommand{\ig}{\includegraphics}
```

Don't use `\in`, because it's preempted.

Comment: but is that what is wanted? I would have thought the ask is to include the .tex file via \input into the normal flow not as a box that is subject to rotation scaling etc. (not that I think it is a good idea to combine the different functions)

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Judging from the file names, the case seems to point to files containing picture code.

Comment: maybe I had read it as the text describing things ... but who knows :-)